# Connect Telerik in C# to PostgreSql db

Tags: c#, postgresql, telerik

I want to make a connection from my project that using Telerik to the PostgreSql database. After that i will make the CRUD, but i always failed to make the connection. I had already try the telerik docs but it still failed. I'm using visual studio 2012 and Npgsql as the driver. And i want to make connection with entity data model. Please anyone help me. I need the real tutorial with this. I makes web project

Answer (score 0):

Using system.configuration you can try to call the app.config file.

Try this one:

```
http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/deprecated/quick-start-scenarios/asp.net-mvc/quickstart-mvc-conn-string
```

How about this one:

App.config file:

> configuration>
>   connectionStrings>
>   add name="npgsql" connectionString="User >ID=npg_username;Password=npg_password;Server=server_Ip_or_localhost;Database=np>g_dbname;timeout=1000;Pooling=False;
>     Pooling=false;INTEGRATED >SECURITY=False; CommandTimeout=120" providerName="Npgsql"/>
>   /connectionStrings>
>   /configuration>

Note: Add references npgdll to your project

```
    TO YOUR CODE BEHIND:

    using System.Configuration;
    using Npgsql;
    using System.Data;


    private static DataSet GetTData(ref string msg)
        {
            String Query = Query = @"select column1,column2 from table1";

                String connstr =           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["npgsql"].ToString();
            NpgsqlConnection cnn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstr);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter adp = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(Query, cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {

                adp.Fill(ds);
                msg = String.Empty;
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                msg = e.Message;
                return ds;
            }
            finally
            {
                ds.Dispose();
                if (cnn != null)
                {
                    cnn.Close();
                    cnn.Dispose();
                    adp.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }



To use this:


     private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         String error = string.empty

     DataSet ds = new Dataset();
     ds= GetTData(ref error);
    if(error!=string.empty )
     {
      MessageBox.Show(error);
      return;
      }
    }
```

Comment: data access can't be installed

Comment: How did you set up your connection string? just need some idea.

Comment: that's what i need. I want to connect it manually, because i got a lot of problem with entity data model connection

Comment: Do you have app.config file from your project?

Comment: copy it to your web.config file the code above.. not include the function

Comment: i want to make it with entity data model